# Umbraco task scheduler to run on specific day

Tags: umbraco, scheduler

can anybody tell me how to set Umbraco scheduler to run on a specific day instead of using seconds in the interbal part of the settings:

I have also installed the package TaskScheduler but never got it running

Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend using the Umbraco scheduler as it is is largely dependent on your application being active e.g. the app pool is running. I would recommend that you use a scheduled task on your server if your architecture supports it to be able to run the task you mention.

Comment: See the official Umbraco Wiki relating to this issue here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/run-the-scheduler-at-certain-times

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. jessipin, my application is an ecommerce website so it's always active. i can run the built in umbraco task scheduler which is in the umbracoSettings.config file, but i want to run it on specifid time as opposed to setting the interval in seconds which i find very silly. i know you mentioned the wiki but this is using XSLT which i have no idea how to use, so any help would be appreciated :). thanks

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that your application is always active? Do you understand the app pool? To maintain activeness, you would have to be getting traffic to your site consistently like every 20 minutes or so otherwise your application pool will time out as this is the way IIS works. If you application pool times out, Umbraco technically will no longer be running until the next person visits. When this happens, the app pool will be refreshed and any Umbraco scheduled tasks will be run straight away. This is why it is best to trigger timed actions from the server rather than the application.

Comment: Have you tried https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ucronos/

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the concerns over whether your application will keep running, you could achieve this by setting your task to run every 5 minutes and then, in the code for the task, check the time to see whether you should do anything.

If it's not time-critical and you want to run the task at around midnight, for example, you could set the schedule for every 60 minutes (to make sure you don't run twice in any one hour). In the task, if the 'Hour' component of the current time is 0, run your code - otherwise, do nothing!

Comment: How does running the task every 40 min ensure you wont run twice in the same hour? what if the first run was at HH:10 ? wouldn't the the next run be at HH:50 ?